# check if input form value (int) is less than expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is about validating a form. I am doing a validation of two fields, one of them receives the value in decimal, example ($ 500.00), is already with mask.

In this field that receives the value, it can not be less than 300.00.

If it is smaller 300.00, a message will appear saying the value has to be greater than 300.00.

Summary: The validation checks that it is empty, but does not check if the (number) int is less than $ 300

I'm using it this way (there's more code, in short):

```
function valid_simulation(form1) {
    if (form1.valor.value == ' ') { 
        alert("value is not valid");
        return false;
    }
    if (form1.valor.value <= 300) {
        alert("value is not valid");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it , but what is the question?

Comment: you better compare to type `int` instead of `string`, `'500 '` should be `500` only, and you had a space in the string for `'500 '`, which it might not able to compare correctly

Comment: Hi Se0ng11, I tried it that way, but I did not succeed too.

Comment: Hi Jakub Ch, my question is: in the validation, I am checking if the value placed in the input is a value less than 300 int, if it is less I will present a message asking to put a value greater than 300 int. the error message I already have ready, I just need to verify that the value is less than 300 int

Comment: Your logic is assuming that `form1.valor.value` is actually a `Number`: you can check that by logging `typeof form1.valor.value` to the console, and see what you get. If it is a string, your validation will not work. Use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic concept is correct: set the message when the if statement test is falsy. Something like the following:

```
function showFormError(message) {
    $("#alertBox").text(message)
}

if (isInvalid) { showFormError("We have a problem.") }
```

Comment: Hi, The error message I already have, what I need is to check if the value placed in the input is a value less than 300 int,

Comment: I'm really not sure what your issue is. Terry hits it on the head above. Maybe you can make a small jsbin to show the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

If the dollar mark is the issue, You can split it and validate.

```
var userInput = $("#inputData").val();
  if(userInput.includes("$")) {
     var splitArray = userInput.split("$");
     if (typeof splitArray[1] && parseFloat(splitArray[1]) < 300){
         alert("Amount Not valid");
     } 
}
```

Comment: Hi CCoder, I think the way might be this, but I tried using your example, but I have not been successful yet. I'm going to continue the tests. Thanks.